# Так и не разобрался нужно вставить в центр заголовок и другую инфу

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование, вёрстка, веб-дизайн

```css
body {
  background-image: url("/Users/kamil/Desktop/ Mebel/изображения /body.jpg");
  height: 100%;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.top-menu {
  background: #630000;
  box-shadow: 3px 0 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  padding: 15px;
}

.top-menu:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.navbar-logo {
  display: inline-block;
}

.menu-main {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  float: right;
}

.menu-main li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.menu-main a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  line-height: 61px;
  padding-left: 50px;
  font-size: 18px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-family: 'Arimo', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #EAE2C9;
  transition: .3s linear;
}

.menu-main a:before {
  content: "";
  width: 9px;
  height: 9px;
  background: #EAE2C9;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: rotate(45deg) translateX(6.5px);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .3s linear;
}

.menu-main a:hover:before {
  opacity: 1;
}

@media (max-width: 660px) {
  .menu-main {
    float: none;
    padding-top: 20px;
  }
  .top-menu {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px 0 0 0;
  }
  .menu-main a {
    padding: 0 10px;
  }
  .menu-main a:before {
    transform: rotate(45deg) translateX(-6px);
  }
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .menu-main li {
    display: block;
  }
}

.container {
  background-color: #EAE2C9;
  border-width: 3px;
  border-color: #000000;
  width: 80%;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  max-width: 1480px;
  min-height: 100px;
  overflow: auto;
  height: 100%;
}

.logoo {
  color: #630000;
  font-family: 'Pattaya', sans-serif;
}

.information {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 2vw;
}
```

```html
<!-- меню в разделе ;контакты;-->
<nav class="top-menu">
  <a class="navbar-logo" href="/Users/kamil/Desktop/ Mebel/index.html"><img src="/Users/kamil/Desktop/ Mebel/изображения /logo.jpg" height="80" width="200"></a>
  <ul class="menu-main">
    <li><a href="">Товары</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Услуги</a></li>
    <li><a href="">О нас</a></li>
    <li><a href="" id="cont">Контакты</a></li>
    <li class="text-center"><a href="8-987-724-1869">tel:8-987-724-186</a></li>
    <li class="text-right"><a href="8-902-100-4887">tel:8-902-100-488</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <h1>«Студия мебели <span class="logoo">Идеал</span>»</h1>
    <!--
<h2>Наши салоны:</h2>
<ol class="information">

<li>Адрес: Марий-Эл, г. Йошкар-Ола, ул. Й.Кырля, д. 25, ТЦ «Планета», 3 этаж. Режим работы: с 10.00 до 20.00 без выходных. Телефон: <a href="8-987-724-1869">8-987-724-1869</a></li>

<li>Адрес: Марий-Эл, Сернурский р-он, пгт. Сернур, ул. Коммунистическая, д. 69.Режим работы: с 9.00 до 18.00, суббота-воскресенье с 9.00.до 16.00 Тел: <a href="8-902-100-4887">8-902-100-4887</a></li></ol>
<p>Почта:<a href="Альпидовский Станислав <stasregion12@ya.ru>">stasregion12@ya.ru</a></p>
-->
  </div>
</div>
```